# List view error 1796249105-372943 (614379870) in Lightning Winter '19

Tags: error-messages, list-view, winter19

Since the Winter '19 release, we have been seeing the following Salesforce error when trying to run some list views in lightning.  It happens for either custom objects or standard objects.  A screenshot of the error is attached.

I logged a case with Salesforce and together with a support tech's help, we were able to discover the issue causing this.

We noticed that this particular list view error only popped up when trying to run a list view in lightning where there was a filter on Owner where Owner was a Queue Name.

[image]

Comment: Hi joaniej, welcome to SFSE. It looks like you're trying to share a solution you've discovered. You can break out that solution from your question and add it here as an **answer** to this question. In a couple of days, you'll be able to accept that answer to mark it as the resolution to the issue.

Comment: Joanie -- this is terrific and the community really appreciates you adding to the knowledge base. Please add in your answer, if you have gotten it from support, a link to the Known Issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix:

When you see this error, switch back to Salesforce Classic. Go to the list view where you received the error. Click the edit button for the list view.

You will notice that the API name of the list view is missing in the Edit screen in the View Unique Name field. The View Unique Name field is blank.

Click into the View Unique Name field, and the unique salesforce name (API Name) of the list view will reappear. Click Save.

Once you do that, you will be able to run the list view in lightning again.

I still have an open case with SF regarding this issue.  Once I see it published as a Winter '19 known issue, I will provide a link here.

Comment: Follow up: Salesforce spent some time on this issue while investigating my case. Their solution was to actually re-create list views where this problem appears.  I'm not sure they intend to add this as a Known Issue.  However, they aren't going to do anything further to fix it.